# Spring Aspectj Around advice does not work with interface implementations

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, interceptor

I have one interface and its implementations.

```
interface A{
    String methodA();
    String methodB();
}

public class Impl1 implements A{

    @Override
    public String methodA() {
        methodB();
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String methodB() {
        return "";
    }
}

public class Impl2 implements A{

    @Override
    public String methodA() {
        methodB();
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String methodB() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

What i want to intercept when any of the implementations of A interface && execution of methodB().

```
@Around("within(com.bla.bla.A+) && execution(* methodB(..))")
```

But this did not work. When i remove execution part, it works but for calling method of the outside. Any idea would be appreciated.

Note: methodb is not triggered direcly out of the interface. it triggers in interface implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring AOP works on proxies. Calling methodB() from methodA() is called a self-invocation. Spring AOP will not be able to advice the method call to methodB() from methodA() , as it will not go through the proxy.

Spring reference documentation : [Understanding AOP Proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) . Read through the section starting with *The key thing to understand here is that the client code inside the main(..)*

Comment: That is a huge limitation